# Updating options for select2 component - vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jquery-select2, vue-component

I am currently learning vue js. I have created one select component which I currently use for selecting the "Rest day" and "Work days" of an employee. Basically, what I want is to remove the selected rest day in the options of the 2nd select input(Work days).

I have manage to load the default values but I can't find a way to update the options for the 2nd select input if the first input was changed.

```
Vue.component('select-component',{
    props: ['options'],
  mounted() {
    var self = this;
    $(this.$el).select2({
        data: this.options
    })
    .on('change', function(e){
        self.$emit('input', $(e.target).val())
    });
  },
  template: '<select></select>'
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    days: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Saturday'],
    workDays: [],
    selectedRestDay: 'Sunday',
    selectedWorkDays: []
  },
  created() {
    this.getWorkDaysOptions();
  },
  methods: {
    getWorkDaysOptions: function() {
        var arr = Object.assign(this.workDays, this.days);
        this.workDays = _.pull(arr, this.selectedRestDay)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    selectedRestDay: function() {
        this.getWorkDaysOptions();
    }
  }
})
```

Here's an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/memoo/gh5nrc9q/) of what I'm working on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my fork

https://jsfiddle.net/b5kf2Lyr/

What I did is that now we have `workDaysOptions` computed data which will always return `days` w/o the selected rest day. In `select-component` I added a watcher for `options` prop so we could reinit the select2 instance when `options` change.

Note that I'm assigning the select2 jQuery object to `this.$select2` which is not a vue data, so it's not reactive(we don't need it to be).

This could be polished much more, but I hope it would answer your question.

Comment: Okay I understand now, thank you for the guidelines @Zlatev, this is what I'm trying to figure out. Cheers!